# How do I change the text editor used by Git to micro?

Tags: git, text-editor

I like [the Micro text editor](https://micro-editor.github.io/). I prefer it to `nano`, personally. However, even when I have it installed, Git defaults to `nano`. How can I change what text editor `git commit` uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy. All you have to do is this, and the next time you commit, Git will use `micro` instead of `nano`.

```
$ git config --global core.editor "micro"
```

This is pretty flexible. We can set it back to `nano`:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

Or we can have it use `vi`:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "vi"
```

This will work for most text editors. I only have those three on my system right now, but that should work for others, like `emacs`, too.

Once you've run the above commands, you'll see this added to your global user file at `~/.gitconfig`:

```bash
[core]
    editor = micro
```

The `--global` option is what tells it to edit the global user file at `~/.gitconfig`.